# SQL Server How to insert multiple values while excluding repeating values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm developing a query for a program where user has to enter one or multiple multiple values into a DB table.

The issue with the query is when you try to insert multiples values it could be that some of those values are repeated in the tables and the warning will only display one repeated value at a time and that might be a problem when you are working with a 1000+ values.

**Error Message:**

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'ItemWebCategory' with unique index 'IX_StyleID_WebCategoryID'. The duplicate key value is (1109068, 99999).

**Query**

```
insert into ItemWebCategory (Style_id,WebCategoryID) 
    select distinct Style_id,WebCategoryID = '99999' 
    from ItemCategory 
    where style_id in ('1109068','168175', '68435', '545457', '69189')
```

**Question**

How can I modify the query so it may skip/exclude all repeating values and only insert the values that do no exist on the table?

Comment: Use a `WHERE` to check the values don't exist or use a `MERGE`?

Comment: `WebCategoryID = '99999'`   is that a boolean field?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ItemWebCategory ( Style_id, WebCategoryID ) 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Style_id,
    '99999' AS WebCategoryID
FROM ItemCategory WHERE Style_id NOT IN (
    SELECT Style_id FROM ItemWebCategory
);
```

The `NOT IN` excludes any `Style_id` values that already exist in `ItemWebCategory`.

Comment: `NOT IN` should be avoided because it produces incorrect results on nullable columns. Use `NOT EXISTS` or `EXCEPT` instead

Answer (score 0):

You have two straight-forward options:

- **`NOT EXISTS`**

```sql
insert into ItemWebCategory (Style_id,WebCategoryID) 
    select distinct Style_id,WebCategoryID = '99999' 
    from ItemCategory ic
    where style_id in ('1109068','168175', '68435', '545457', '69189') 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM ItemWebCategory iwc
            WHERE ic.Style_id = iwc.Style_id
        );
```

- **`EXCEPT`**

```sql
insert into ItemWebCategory (Style_id,WebCategoryID) 
    select Style_id,WebCategoryID = '99999' 
    from ItemCategory
    where style_id in ('1109068','168175', '68435', '545457', '69189') 
    EXCEPT
    SELECT Style_id
    FROM ItemWebCategory;
```

Now there's no need for `DISTINCT` because `EXCEPT` implies `DISTINCT`

- **One more useful option is a `MERGE`.** This has performance benefits due to Halloween Protection (an entire subject in itself) [as explained by Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/sql-plan/halloween-problem-part-3):

```sql
MERGE ItemWebCategory AS target
USING (
    select Style_id, WebCategoryID = '99999' 
    from ItemCategory
    where style_id in ('1109068','168175', '68435', '545457', '69189')
) AS source
ON target.Style_id = source.Style_id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (Style_id, WebCategoryID)
VALUES (source.Style_id, source.WebCategoryID);
```